# Is there a way to generate a random number using a Minimum and Maximum value using Single in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, random

I'm looking for a random number generator that I can use to alter the size of a picture box on my form. Currently, I have this solution found here on StackOverflow:

```
    Public Function GetRandomNumber(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
        Static lcGenerator As System.Random = New System.Random()
        Return lcGenerator.Next(Min, Max)
    End Function
```

As it stands, the function will generate a random integer between the range specified. This is great, but I am noticing that often the picture box doesn't change in size with a decent amount of variation. The following code shows how I am calculating variance in size:

```
Dim lcModifier As Decimal = (GetRandomNumber(-20, 11) * 0.01)

pbForeground.Width = CInt((0.4 - lcModifier) * pbBackground.Width)
pbForeground.Height = CInt((0.4 - lcModifier) * pbBackground.Height)
```

The idea is that I generate a random number between -20 and 11. This would yield a 20% increase or 10% decrease, as the minimum is inclusive but the maximum is exclusive, and I am subtracting the modifier.

I had the idea to use a Single value in place of the integer value. The Single type gave me more "room" away from 0 than a Double would, but the Next method only uses Integer values, and we're back to my initial problem.

The NextDouble method works differently to the Next method, and I am unable to specify Min and Max values, nor can I generate a negative value.

Is there any way I can generate a value using Minimum and Maximum bounds that is not close to zero?

Thanks,
sunnyCr

Comment: You could check if `Math.Abs(lcModifier) < 0.2`, say, and if so generate another value for `lcModifier`.

Comment: Use NextDouble() instead, give it the desired range with min + (max - min) * value

Comment: @HansPassant if i am not mistaken, NextDouble() has no arguments and generates a Double between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble?view=netframework-4.8      How should I give it a range?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I looked in the MSDN for the Math.Abs() Method and found that one exists for Decimal numbers but I don't know how to call that specific method. After typing Math.Abs(), and hovering over the .Abs() section, the function shows "As Integer". After Ctrl + Click on the .Abs(), I can see that Functions exist for Math.Abs() As Decimal but I don't see any difference in the way they are declared. How can i differentiate between what method of .Abs() I want to call? Forgive me, I am a new programmer. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise - License provided by Education institution

Comment: @sunnyCr The compiler will automatically pick which overload (of Math.Max) to use by looking at the argument - if you pass it a Decimal, it will use the Decimal version of the method. (That goes for functions and subs in general.)

Comment: If you get a random number from 0 to 1, then just threat it as a percentage.   (rnd_result * 31) - 20

Comment: @the_lotus The idea was to have a *negative* 10% or *positive* 20 percent increase. If i am not mistaken, randomly generating only positive values would introduce some sort of selection bias when choosing if it is a positive or negative number.

Comment: @sunnyCr You have a range of 30 between -10 and 20. Just do a random from 0 to 30 and subtract to shift the range into the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

The NextDouble return a percentage. You just need to multiply by the range of value and then translate to the desired starting position.

```
Function GetRandomNumber(ByVal low As Double, high As Double) As Double
    Static rng As New Random

    Return (rng.NextDouble() * (high - low)) + low
End Function
```